# Order By with Foreign Object Field if it exists

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do a query where I would order by foreign object if there is one - or by a local field.

Example:

```
class AuditorData(Base):
    auditor_weight = models.FloatField()
    audited_object = models.ForeignKey('MyObject', related_name='audits')

class MyObject(Base):
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

Basically I want to do order by Max(audits.auditor_weight) but if there is no audits, it will order by 'weight'

How could I create a query to do so

I tried to do use annotation and aggregation, with coalesce order_by, but it doesn't work.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [conditional statement](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max, Case, When, FloatField, F

MyObject.objects.all().annotate(count=Count('audits')).annotate(
    max=Case(
        When(count=0, then=F('weight')),
        When(count__gt=0, then=Max('audits__auditor_weight')),
        output_field=FloatField()
        )
    )
).order_by('max')
```

Comment: Just want to point out you'll need to add `.order_by('max')` on the end there.

Comment: Opps. Thanks for mentioning. Updated the answer @Bott0610

Comment: I think it is missing the `import F`
I will try your solution soon.